# Select top 10 row from Matrix in R

Tags: r

I have gotten the matrix in R as shown below. If I use the command

*rows <- which(sim_results == min(sim_results))*

It will return 17 and 854.

Now I would like to retrieve the top 10 records sorted by scores. i.e. to get values from 17 to 630 shown in the matrix.

I tried to do the coding as per below, however it didn't retrieve from 17 to 630 but retrieved values as highlighted. Anything I did wronlgy?

[image]
[image]

Comment: `head(sim_results, 10)`.

Comment: use the `order` and then do as @RuiBarradas suggested

Comment: Please save the rstudio tag for rstudio specific problems, like if your code works on the command line but not in RStudio.

Comment: Or `sim_results[1:10, ]`. Looks like your data is already ordered...

Comment: Hi, Please refer to my rephrased question..

Comment: If you just want the row names, then instead of `head(sim_results, 10)` you can do `head(rownames(sim_results), 10)` or `rownames(sim_results)[1:10]`. Replace `sim_results` with `sim_results[order(sim_results$V1), ]` if you want to (re?)sort it first.

Comment: Also, from your syntax it is evident that you have a `data.frame`, not a `matrix`. These differences matter. I would strongly encourage you to [make copy/pasteable reproducible examples in the future with `dput()` or simulated data, this link will explain how.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/903061) Pictures of data are really terrible.